# Visual Studio 2013 shared folder between two projects in one solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, path

i wonder is that possible to use relative path to access a folder outside the project? Example: project A and project B in one solution retrieve the same image from the same folder. I had try to save the folder in C:\ but it is block the file access. I also had tried file:///C:\Image\ but still cant make it...
Anyone had any idea about this?

Comment: In exactly what context are you talking about?  A project accessing a folder and an application accessing a folder are two very different things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use content links for all files in some directory outside of project dir.
For example this code inside csproj file

```
<Content Include="..\Common\**">
  <Link>Common\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
</Content>
```

will add links to all files inside the folder ../Common.